# Trigger: execute query that fired it if condition is verifyed

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I'm working on postgres, and i would know if there's a easy way to execute inside trigger the invoking query without write it again inside trigger. I'm explain myself. 
I have a INSERT query on a table and a trigger executing BEFORE INSERT. If a condition is verifyed, then i would execute the query without rewrite it inside trigger (using NEW variables).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, try:

```
IF (condition) THEN  
    RETURN new;
ELSE  
    -- statements
END IF;
```

Osvaldo

Comment: you would probably want to RETURN NULL (to skip the row) or RAISE EXCEPTION to abort the transaction in your ELSE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on what query do you have, but you cound use a function and write your query inside it:

```
create table test (number int);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_test_insert("number" integer)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
insert into test (number) -- this is your insert query
    select $1
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tr_fn_test_insert()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
begin
perform fn_test_insert(new.number + 1); -- calling your insert query with new + 1
    return new;                         -- as example
end
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_test_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON test
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN ((new.number < 10))
EXECUTE PROCEDURE tr_fn_test_insert();

select fn_test_insert(1);
```

Comment: Write the query inside trigger is what i would avoid!

Comment: I'm working with SQL Server and user Postgres only for fun. Why do you avoid that?

Comment: In this case I don't see anything wrong with it, because you are only inserting into a table.  However when people do a lot of complex queries in triggers, they run into fun problems, performance-wise.  Keep in mind the trigger query is run once per row, so you can run into very complex performance issues if you aren't careful.